# Adding Serializable causes Xslt to throw StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, xslt, orleans

I am working on getting orleans working with our website. I have gotten the Silos started, and my website starts, but when I tried to make a call to the grain, I realized I had forgotten to add the [Serializable] attribute to my class.

After doing that, I instead get a StackOverflowException from calling Load on an XslCompiledTransform, in a seperate file which has no references to Orleans. This StackOverflowException is happening while the website is starting up, and that line is run successfully before adding the Serializable attribute.

Are there any non obvious reasons that I may be missing that would explain how these two things are related?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @CKoch, could you please post more context? I'd need to see some code for the type being serialized and where the issue is showing up. Do you know which methods are included in the stack overflow? By the way, questions of this nature can also be posted on GitHub issues